# Backbone & SignalR BroadcastModelDestroyed not working

Tags: javascript, c#, backbone.js, signalr

Utilising backbone.signalr.js I have create and update working so that changes to my model on one client is automatically pushed to other clients. I can not get BroadcastModelDestroyed to communicate with my registered clients when I delete a model.

It is a demo app for learning purposes so happy to share any part with you to find why Delete does not work.

Here is my Delete Api

```
[HttpDelete]
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id) {
try {
    using(var entities = new BlogRollBackboneEntities()) {
        var foundBlog = entities.Blogs.Include("Tags").SingleOrDefault(b_ => b_.BlogId == id);
        if(foundBlog == null) {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Can not find the blog in the database");
        }
        entities.Blogs.Remove(foundBlog);
        entities.SaveChanges();

        BlogHub.BroadcastModelDestroyed(foundBlog); // <----- THIS DOESN'T DO ANYTHING???
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, foundBlog);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
}
```

}

Here is my delete function in my Backbone view

```
delete: function () {
            this.model.destroy({
                success: function (model, respose, options) {
                    Blogs.blogs.remove(model);
                },
                error: function (model, xhr, options) {
                    alert("Something went wrong while deleting the blog :(");
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is the SignalR Javascript code

```
(function ($, Blogs) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // signalr sync
        new Backbone.SignalR("blogHub").syncUpdates(Blogs.blogs);
        $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function () {
                console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);
                Blogs.blogs.fetch({
                    success: function (collection4, response) {
                        console.log("We have fetch(ed) all the blogs from the server :)");
                    },
                    error: function (model, xhr, options) {
                        console.log("Something went wrong fetch(ing) the blogs from the server :(");
                    }
                });
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log('Could not Connect!');
            });
    });

})(jQuery, window.Blogs = window.Blogs || {});
```

Here is the SignalR Hub code

```
 public abstract class BackboneModelHub<HubT, ModelT> : Hub
        where HubT : IHub
        where ModelT : class
    {
        private static IHubContext HubContext
        {
            get { return GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HubT>(); }
        }

        private static JsonSerializerSettings Settings
        {
            get { return new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }; }
        }

        private static ModelT Deserialize(string data)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelT>(data, Settings);
        }

        private static string Serialize(ModelT model)
        {
            return model != null ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Settings) : "{}";
        }

        private static string Serialize(IEnumerable<ModelT> models)
        {
            return models != null ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(models, Settings) : "[]";
        }

        public static void BroadcastModelCreated(ModelT item)
        {
            HubContext.Clients.All.created(Serialize(item));
        }

        public static void BroadcastModelUpdated(ModelT item)
        {
            HubContext.Clients.All.updated(Serialize(item));
        }

        public static void BroadcastModelDestroyed(ModelT item)
        {
            HubContext.Clients.All.destroyed(Serialize(item));
        }

        public static void BroadcastCollectionReset(IEnumerable<ModelT> items)
        {
            HubContext.Clients.All.resetItems(Serialize(items));
        }

        protected virtual ModelT CreateModel(ModelT model_)
        {
            return model_;
        }

        protected virtual ModelT UpdateModel(ModelT model_)
        {
            return model_;
        }

        protected virtual ModelT FindModel(ModelT model_)
        {
            return null;
        }

        protected virtual IEnumerable<ModelT> FindModels()
        {
            return new List<ModelT>();
        }

        protected virtual ModelT DeleteModel(ModelT model_)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public string Create(string data)
        {
            var model = Deserialize(data);
            model = CreateModel(model);

            var result = Serialize(model);

            Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).created(result);
            return result;
        }

        public string Update(string data)
        {
            var model = Deserialize(data);
            model = UpdateModel(model);

            var result = Serialize(model);
            Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).updated(result);
            return result;
        }

        public string Find(string data)
        {
            var model = Deserialize(data);
            model = FindModel(model);

            var result = Serialize(model);
            return result;
        }

        public string FindAll()
        {
            var items = FindModels();

            var result = Serialize(items);
            return result;
        }

        public string Destroy(string data)
        {
            var model = Deserialize(data);
            model = DeleteModel(model);

            var result = Serialize(model);
            Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).destroyed(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

And here is the rather bereft BlogHub class. It is empty as per the backbone.signalr documentation (https://github.com/BillWagner/backbone.signalr)

```
public class BlogHub: BackboneModelHub<BlogHub, Blog> {
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: And where is `SignalR` involved?

Comment: SignalR is used to ensure all clients are kept in sync. Works wonderfully for inserts and updates.

I have added SignalR code to the question

Comment: Could you please show the full hub? Thanks!

Comment: Updated to show the full hub code :)

Comment: anyone know of this answer?